# How to tell if a video has metatags injected

Tags: video-encoding

I've started streaming videos and it turns out that users can't seek into my videos if they don't have metatags injected. I use the flv format.

I have installed yamdi and but it doesn't really seem to come with a good manual.

I'm trying to write some sort of script that will inject these tags into my whole video library ( about 300 videos) but I would like to know if there is a way of determining if a video has already been injected

Comment: Can't seek if no metatags injected? The meta tags are stuff like artist, album etc. right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like [getid3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) to analyze a media file for various information.

Answer (score 0):

You can check AVI files with:

```
avinfo <filename>
```

and Matroska files with:

```
mkvinfo <filename>
```